# Django: Annotate list of related fields

Tags: django, django-aggregation, django-annotate, django-subquery

I have an Company and User models with a related model CompanyRecruiter:

```py
class CompanyRecruiter(models.Model):

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="company_recruiters")
    recruiter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="company_recruiters")
```

I want to annotate the list of user ids of users who are recruiters for companies to be able to filter on them later:

```py
Company.objects.annotate(some_stuff=some_other_stuff).values_list("user_ids", flat=True)
# [ [1, 2], [1, 56], [] ]
```

I already tried with Custom Aggregates and Subqueries without success.
I use postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need output similar to the commented section in your example code, you should probably query the `CompanyRecruiter` model:

```
recruiters = CompanyRecruiter.objects.values_list('organization', 'recruiter')
recruiter_list = [[o, r] for o, r in recruiters]
```

However, in the comments you have indicated that you want to specifically query the `Company` model. You should be able to do this with the Postgresql aggregating function [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
Company.objects.annotate(recruiter_ids=ArrayAgg('company_recruiters__recruiter'))
```

Comment: I need to apply the annotation on a Company queryset. Querying the CompanyRecruiter table would make me do 2 DB calls and I would like to keep all in one to be efficient.